# Rails rspec test failing when trying to add a duplicate node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Im using rspec to test an API i am developing to communicate with my android app.

For some reason when i run this test

```
it "tries to add an existing node (same mac address but better signal)" do
  node = Node.create(ssid: "test1", mac: 0, signal: 100)
  post "/api/nodes/", node: { ssid: "test1", mac: 0, signal: 50 }, format: :json
end
```

I get an error about node being a duplicate on the "mac" field however i check this in the controller to make sure it shouldnt happen

```
def create
  @node = Node.find_by(mac: params[:mac])  #This checks for duplicates but doesnt seem to work
  if @node.nil?
    @node = Node.new(node_params)
    if @node.save                          #somehow its getting to here but the save is failing
      render :show, status: :created       #because there is a duplicate
    end
  else
```

It only seems to be in the unit test this is happening, with a real word test it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params[:mac]` is `nil`

```
post "/api/nodes/", node: { ssid: "test1", mac: 0, signal: 50 }, format: :json
```

This line sends `params[:node][:ssid]`, `params[:node][:mac]` and `params[:node][:signal]`, so you should change your action to:

```
def create
  @node = Node.find_by(mac: params[:node][:mac]) 
  if @node.nil?
    @node = Node.new(node_params)
    if @node.save                         
      render :show, status: :created      
    end
  else
```

PS: I assume you have this method:

```
def node_params
  params.require(:node).permit(:ssid, :mac, signal)
end
```

If it is:

```
def node_params
  params.permit(:ssid, :mac, signal)
end
```

Then you shouldn't wrap them in `node:` when posting:

```
post "/api/nodes/", ssid: "test1", mac: 0, signal: 50, format: :json
```

and

```
@node = Node.find_by(mac: params[:mac])
```

will work

Comment: One other issue is signal: seems to be a string by the time it reaches my controller however with my android app it remains an integer.  Is that intended?

Comment: @dmateos this is different question, but take a look here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/418